# System32 and SysWOW64 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, 64-bit

What is "SysWOW64" and how does it work?

Are SysWOW64 and System32 both used/loaded into RAM during the Windows 7 boot?

Comment: Oddly enough Syswow64 is legacy 32 bit versions of windows apps like taskmanager and cmd.

Comment: It just stands for windows on windows.

Comment: [Interview with an Ex-Microsoftie](https://secretgeek.net/ex_ms) is excellent about this. TL;DR:  System32 is for 64-bit files and SysWOW64 is for 32-bit files.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Executive summary

Microsoft does things backwards sometimes, and this is yet another example of this.  `System32` is the **64-bit** Windows system directory and `SysWOW64` is the **32-bit** Windows system directory — entirely the opposite way around to what the directory names would suggest.

## Details

In Windows, there is a "Windows" directory and a "System" directory, and this has been true all of the way back to when Windows was 16-bit.

Windows programs are *supposed* to locate them using system API functions such as [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetSystemDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); and if everyone had done that the world would be quite different at this point.  But too many people [foolishly](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100128-00/?p=15153) hardwired the actual name of the directory, `\Windows\System32`, into their programs, and then ported those programs from 32-bit Windows to 64-bit Windows.  As a consequence, a whole lot of programs were looking for **64-bit** executables and libraries in the `\Windows\System32` directory, whose name they had hardwired.  (Ironically, there was the same issue when migrating from 16-bit Windows to 32-bit Windows.  [The 16-bit "System" directory was `\Windows\System`, usually](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041008-00/?p=37623).)

So the people at Microsoft chose to make `\Windows\System32` the directory that *native*, 64-bit, Windows programs would find the 64-bit executables and libraries in, and, since [32-bit programs run on top of a shim layer *anyway* in 64-bit Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081222-00/?p=19763), accesses to the "System" directory by 32-bit programs are redirected to a new `\Windows\SysWOW64` directory.

Hence the bizarre situation that now obtains.

Answer (score 13):

[WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) stands for Windows 32 on Windows 64:

> WoW64 (Windows 32-bit On Windows 64-bit) is a subsystem of the Windows operating system that is capable of running 32-bit applications and is included on all 64-bit versions of Windows — including Windows 2000 Limited Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, IA-64 and x64 versions of Windows Server 2003, as well as 64-bit versions of Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, and Windows 7.

Comment: I'm all voted out for today but this is a good answer... future +1

Answer (score 4):

It means System Windows(x32) on Windows x64. It contains all x32 system files for compatibility. It runs so 32 bit apps can.