# Some files in System32 not accessible outside Explorer on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I've got a strange problem regarding accessing a file (more specifically SnippingTool.exe) in Windows 7's System32 directory. I can see/run/access the file when opening the directory in Explorer (and the command prompt), I can copy it to other places (and it will be perfectly accessible in other locations), but when trying to access it in any way from other applications (examples include mintty, Notepad++ and a Java program), they simply report it as not existing.

I've noticed that this applies to many other files in System32 as well.

My problem is very much like the one posted [here](https://superuser.com/q/282252) except this isn't about files I have copied into the directory, it's Windows' own files. This only happens on one of my computers (but it is the case on a friend's computer as well), the other happily lets all applications access the file, and I am absolutely clueless as to what is causing this.

Does anyone have suggestions for this? Both computers are running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In x86-64 Windows NT, 64-bit applications see the real `System32` directory.  32-bit applications, however, that read what they think to be the `System32` directory are actually reading the `SysWOW64` directory.  [This SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/284701) explains the details.  In the 32-bit programs, you are seeing one directory by that name.  In the 64-bit programs you are seeing another.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer. Is there any remedy to this situation, say, if I wanted to open a file affected by this in a 32-bit application? (other than copying the file from System32 to SysWOW64, which apparently works, but isn't a particularly pretty solution)

Comment: For myself, I just made a link from `System64` to `System32`, so that 32-bit programs can see the true `System32` directory as `System64`.

Comment: 32-bit programs can see the system32 folder as 'sysnative'.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, this issue was giving me headaches beyond reason.

Comment: They do not do so entirely properly.  They don't see a directory entry in the parent directory by that name, for example.  My little link, in contrast, is visible as a proper directory entry in the parent, and also has semantics in 64-bit programs that are identical to its semantics in 32-bit programs.

Comment: Thank you, JdeBP!  BTW, for anyone who doesn't know how to make links in Windows, "mklink /D C:\Windows\System64 C:\Windows\System32" should do it.